# incompatible types when creating thread in Windows

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio

I have created an app in which I want a thread to handle listen-UDP separately and make me a buffer, but when I try to pass it to thread it says there are compatibility issues

```
hThread = CreateThread( 
          NULL,                   // default security attributes
          0,                      // use default stack size  
          start,       // thread function name
          &buffer,          // argument to thread function 
          0,                      // use default creation flags 
          &dwThreadId);
```

my start function is

```
void start(buffer_t *buffer)
{

    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
    int slen , recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;
}
```

and the error is

> 1 IntelliSense: argument of type "void (*)(buffer_t *buffer)" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE" c:\users\madihamalik\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\udp listener\udp listener\listerner.c    189 12  UDP listener

Comment: The thread routine for [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx) is required to match `DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID)`. That's not what you're giving it. Thus the error.

Comment: what can i possibly do with it?

Comment: Um, change your start function to match what is expected?

Comment: after fixing the function declaration, add a stack varuable: char * buffer = theParameterName;   the use buffer as before.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code that might help you..

```
DWORD start(LPVOID lpdwThreadParam)
{
    buffer_t *buffer = (buffer_t *)lpdwThreadParam; //Type cast your argument here
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server, si_other;
    int slen, recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;
    ...
}
```